# Dockerfile ENV var character replace

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Can I do character substitution to set one `ENV` value based on another one?

My scenario...

```
ENV tableauVersion 2019-4-0
ENV tableauVersionDots 2019.4.0

ENV tabcmdURL https://downloads.tableau.com/esdalt/${tableauVersionDots}/tableau-tabcmd-${tableauVersion}_all.deb
```

Obviously, i'd like to be able to define `tableauVersionDots` based on the `tableauVersion` `ENV` variable (i.e. replace `-` with `.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The only substitutions it's possible to do in Dockerfile `ENV` statements are the ones shown in [the Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement): `$variable`, `${variable}`, `${variable:-default}`, or `${variable:+yes it is set}`.

For URLs like that you don't really need them in an environment variable.  If you do need to compute it and then fetch it you could do it within a single `RUN` statement

```sh
RUN tableauVersionDots=$(echo "$tableauVersion" | sed 's/-/./g') \
 && curl -LO https://downloads.tableau.com/esdalt/${tableauVersionDots}/tableau-tabcmd-${tableauVersion}_all.deb
```

The variable setting won't survive beyond this `RUN` statement (and in shell space I haven't even bothered to `export` it) but that's probably okay just for fetching a URL.